# Simple file sharing web application

Tags: software-recommendation, file-sharing, webapps

I am looking for a simple web application that may be deployed to a web server like Apache or nginx, serving though HTTP(S) the contents of a certain folder. Most web browsers already support this to some extent, but I would like to have more advanced functionalities, like:

- filter files by name
- order files by size, date, etc
- select multiple files for simultaneous download

The requirement for such application is that it runs or Ubuntu server. I  prefer open source, but would also consider freeware.

Implementing technologies are not important, JavaScript, PHP, HTML, all good as long as it fulfils the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[filebrowser](https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser) presents various of the features I am searching for. It is more centered on file upload and management, but also supports download.

List of functionalities:

- file listings in mosaic or list
- delete
- move
- rename
- upload
- create new files and directories.
- direct single file download
- multiple file download as `.zip`, `.tar`, `.tar.gz`, `.tar.bz2` or `.tar.xz`

[image]